# Credit card payment tracking inside Android application

Tags: android, credit-card

I am building an expense manager application and I was wondering if it is possible to track credit card spendings within an Android application. Users can input their credit card information and every time they make a purchase, the app will get notified and record the amount spent. I searched online and most resources only point to how you can accept credit card payments.

Comment: You can track it by getting text of incoming messages, but here it is necessary that the same number should be used by user for bank and app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where should the Android app should get the information? There are two alternatives:

1. Let the user enter the data
2. Get the data from the bank.

Bank: How to get the data from the bank depends on the bank. Some send you a notification via sms/email, some show it on a web-site after user login. Therefore it depends on the bank and the country you are living in. AFAIK there is no general API which would allow you to access such data.